# Running jar in java using a specific user

Tags: java, jar, runtime, execute, updates

Let me explain the problem:

**Context**

I have this application that wants to update. It call an updater jar that I have also made. The updater kill the application running the old version and the updater starts up a new one with the new version.

**Problem**

The new version doesn't start unless I run the jar my self. Adding a sleep didn't solve the problem.

**Hypothesis**

Maybe the user running the updater app is java and it doesn't have the priviliges to run the new version

I run the first java with my user than this java application run the jar with "java user" and java user can't run the new version.

Is there a way I can specify a user when I run my jar with the runtime.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C://Temp//myapp.jar");
```

Comment: windows or linux? What do you mean new version does not start?

Comment: It's on Windows
This doesn't work:
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("runas /user:"+utilisateur+" \"C:\\somewhere\\dfs\\app.exe\"");
Neither this
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("runas /user:"+utilisateur+" \"java -jar C:\\somewhere\\dfs\\app.jar\"");

Comment: MyAppV100 need to update. It receive the command with a specific action. It call the updater wich is an external jar. The updater kill MyAppV100 and start MyAppv200 (But it never start unless I call the updater manually) :( Thank you!

Comment: I think you need to run the Jar via Java, something like *java -jar myApp.jar* (obvious you need to supply context to the location of the jar file). You should also use ProcessBuilder, it will make your life easier ;)

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using Windows environment, trying following might help your cause

try the command on the windows system32 path

```
runas /showtrustlevels
```

You should get something like the following:

```
C:\Windows\system32>runas /showtrustlevels
The following trust levels are available on your system:
0x20000 (Basic User)
```

You would then take the value for "Basic User" and run something like the following to start jar:

```
runas /trustlevel:0x20000 "java -jar yourfileName.jar"
```

or you could try this [link](https://superuser.com/questions/262571/how-do-i-easily-elevate-when-running-a-jar-file) it might be useful